# PARENT CHILD SOQL

Tags: soql, query, parent

I have this query which is working but is it possible to only return a list of Accounts where `company__c` exists.

```
SELECT ID, name, (select company__c from VotingRelatedCompanies__r where Relationship_Status__c = 'Active' )  from account
```

`VotingRelatedCompanies__r` is the child relationship name of a lookup(Account).

**Goal**:
Return a list of Accounts where the relationship exists as Active.

**Issue**:
Query returns all Accounts.

**Question**:
Is it possible to structure the query to accomplish goal?

Ultimately I am trying to loop through the `Voting_Relation__c` and update a field on the Account which is another lookup to Account but on the Account object.  I am thinking reducing the number of Account records to process through I can avoid hitting limits such as CPU and/or Query limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a join to find only records which have child records meeting certain criteria.

```
SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Lookup__c FROM Child__c WHERE ...
)
```

So in your case, if your child object is named `VotingRelatedCompany__c`, it would look like:

```
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Company__c
    FROM VotingRelatedCompany__c
    WHERE Relationship_Status__c = 'Active'
)
```